# How can I make sure my phone info is correct?

Tags: samsung, imei

When I check my S23 Ultra phone settings it says it's a 512G Memory and 12G RAM, but when I check it on [imei.info](https://www.imei.info/) website it shows 256G storage and 8G RAM! As I bought it as a renew from Amazon and came without the original box, Which info is correct? Should I return the phone?

I also would like to know if the phone is US version but don't know how can I do that if I don't have the original box?

Comment: Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo.plus), it will give you all the details you are looking for and more

Answer (score 1):

To check

- Goto Settings
- Battery and device care
- Look at Memory and Storage

  It may be that imei shows the default build.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly you **shoud not** return the phone based only on the info shown in an unknown site such as that. A (mostly) trusted source of phone specs is [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s23_ultra-12024.php), which says that your S23 comes with these Memory variants:

> 256GB 8GB RAM, 256GB 12GB RAM, 512GB 12GB RAM, 1TB 12GB RAM

According to the exact model number (shown somewhere in the Settings > About Phone secreen) you can Google its specs in any more or less realiable website.